# Revit Synchronize With Central

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I am wondering if there's any Forge API allow to see who Synchronize With Central (username/time)?

the idea to see who synchronizes the Revit files before start translation to SV.

Comment: Do you happen to know: (i) is this information available in the Revit end user interface? How? (ii) is this information available programmatically through the Revit API? How? If not, then it will probably not be accessible in Forge either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be any Revit API for querying this information.

For Forge, the Get Versions Forge DM API returns the version info, including the users who created the versions. However, when the items are RCM-based models, the users are actually the people who make the corresponding Publishes, rather than  the people who make SWCs...